# Encrypt JavaFX jar with custom Class Loader

Tags: java, security, encryption, javafx, javafx-8

I'm developing a **JavaFx 8** application for windows desktops using **JDK 8 update 60 32 bit** on Windows 8.1 64 bit PC.

I'm shipping the JVM along with the JavaFX program as a self contained application and I really want to add some security besides obfuscation with Proguard by encrypting the Jar files and then decrypting it on runtime but I can't find up to date example that implements that.

I have searched here in SO and googled about it and all the answers say that this isn't the way to go and it's not secure but in fact this method adds a layer of security because as far as I know getting the classes from memory isn't as easy as downloading a decompiler and then getting all the code.

So my questions are:-

1)How to encrypt the Jar files then implement a custom class loader with JavaFX 8 encrypted classes application.

2)I have also found that you can use a custom JVM to decrypt the jars on the fly and it's even more secure!! how to implement that?

Thanks

Comment: `getting the classes from memory isn't as easy as downloading a decompiler and then getting all the code` -- thats the **exact** opposite of reality, nothing is easier than listing all the classes in memory, in fact **every JDK is delivered with a powerful memory-dump tool by default** - its called "jvisualvm" and is found within your `bin` directory. You obviously have some major misconceptions about java. Neither will it ever be possible to achieve machinecode - level obfuscation nor does that make any sense - java operates on *bytecode* hence can be deobfuscated at any time.

Comment: if you want to "protect" your code either set a restrictive license for it or use another language, Java is not intended to "protect" your creations to any extent. You are using the wrong tool.

Comment: another thing : a **decompiler** does not "get you code". At all. What you can EXTRAPOLATE is **assembly mnemonics** - with these, powerful decompilers may **estimate** _possible_ sourcecode - variants; none of which resemble the original ... its like trying to paint a face of a person in great detail while looking at his/her **shadow**. Not possible. This is true even for Java decompilers - but since bytecode is available the assembly-step can be skipped and the estimate will be somewhat close to the original.

Comment: Ofcourse you can list all classes and even fields in memory but I don't think you can review the code that easily.I don't want to prevent decompiling completely as I know it's not possible but I want to make it as difficult as possible.And yes acheiving machine code level is possible using AOT like Excelsior JET but it is expensive.

Comment: And I quote "downloading a decompiler and then getting all the code".I agree a decompiler will never get the exact code but mostly it will get **"enough"** of the code

Comment: `it will get "enough" of the code` - no it wont "get" **anything** from the original machinecode. At all. Not even 1%. Re-read what i wrote. `but I don't think you can review the code that easily` - you're contradicting yourself. With java decompilers, you will get something which is practically identical to the source - with one single exception : variable names, object names ... compile-time symbols in general so you will have to set the names yourself but thats about the entirety of differences.

Comment: `acheiving machine code level is possible using AOT like Excelsior JET` - thats a total language conversion, not an obfuscation / protection - and most of these tools produce very weird, buggy, unstable machinecode which crashes uncontrollably most of the time ... at least thats the experience i made.